# Rename string values automatically in pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe like this:

| Var Name | Val |
| --- | --- |
| a | 11 |
| a | 1 |
| a | 2 |
| b | 3 |
| b | 4 |

I would like to add a column with updated and enumerated "Var Name", something like this

| Var Name | Val | Var Name |
| --- | --- | --- |
| a | 11 | a1 |
| a | 1 | a2 |
| a | 2 | a3 |
| b | 3 | b1 |
| b | 4 | b2 |

My idea is to enumerate the Var Name `(1,2,3...)` till it "recognizes" a new `Var Name and` start enumerating again from 1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`groupby` + `cumcount` is what you need here:

```
df['Var Name2'] = df['Var Name'] + df.groupby('Var Name').cumcount().add(1).astype(str)
```

Output:

```
>>> df
  Var Name  Val Var Name2
0        a   11        a1
1        a    1        a2
2        a    2        a3
3        b    3        b1
4        b    4        b2
```

To add extra characters, such as an underscore:

```
df['Var Name2'] = df['Var Name'] + '_' + df.groupby('Var Name').cumcount().add(1).astype(str)
```

Comment: Thank you very much! 
What if I want to rename it with an underscore? 
a -> a_1
a -> a_2

Comment: Check the bottom of the answer, @Costas. I added another example.